# How can I return a no records found message if results are empty?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get this to either return the variable code or show the message if the query returns empty. Please help me figure this out because this only shows the code but not the error message if blank.

```
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE

 con=mysqli_connect('localhost','XXX','XXX','XXX');
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) // Check connection
 {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();  }

 $Pid = $_GET['Pid'];

 $prodquery = mysqli_query($con,"select product_id, coupon_id from   
 oc_coupon_product where product_id = '$Pid' "); 
 while ($prod = mysqli_fetch_array($prodquery)) {

  $code = $prod['coupon_id'];

   $returnquery = mysqli_query($con,"select coupon_id, code, discount  from   
 oc_coupon where coupon_id = '$code' "); 
  while ($show = mysqli_fetch_array($returnquery)) {
    if(isset($show)) {

       echo "variable is set to  $show[code]";

     } else {
       echo "variable is not set";
     }  
   }
 }
```

Comment: `con` is TYPO. Need to be `$con`.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
$i=0;
while ($show = mysqli_fetch_array($returnquery)) {
 echo "variable is set to  $show[code]";
$i++;
 }  

if ( $i==0) echo "variable is not set";
```

//Or as pointed out in the comments a more "correct" solution would be

```
if($prodquery->num_rows === 0)
    {
        echo 'No results';
    } else {
    while ($show = mysqli_fetch_array($returnquery)) {
     echo "variable is set to  $show[code]";
     } 
}
```

Comment: this is bad idea, because you have in-built function of mysqli to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($show = mysqli_fetch_array($returnquery)) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($show)) {

       echo "variable is set to  $show[code]";

     } else {
       echo "variable is not set";
     }  
}
```

Comment: Why @AlivetoDie?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  because op wan to check query return records count, not inside while. because it will true even $show is empty array

Comment: `$show` will be either be an array or null. It doesn't make sense to call `mysqli_num_rows($show)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to count what has returned.

```
 $returnquery = mysqli_query($con,"select coupon_id, code, discount  from   
 oc_coupon where coupon_id = '$code' ");
 $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($returnquery); 
 if($row_cnt > 0) {
     while ($show = mysqli_fetch_array($returnquery)) {
        echo "variable is set to  $show['code']"; // quote the identifier
     } 
 } else {
     echo "variable is not set";
 }
```

### Warning!

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from any other issues, let me just briefly explain your main logic error.

> this only shows the code but not the error message if blank

This is because you're using `if(isset($show))` to display the error message in a section of code that *is not reachable if* `isset($show)` *evaluates to true*.

When you have iterated all your query results, or if there are no results to iterate, then `mysqli_fetch_array($returnquery)` will return `null`. When that happens, it no longer satisfies the continuation condition for your while loop (null evaluates to false), so the contents of the loop will not be executed, and your code will continue after the loop.

There are various ways to fix it. One way is to set a variable in the while loop and check it afterward to see if any results were shown.

```
while ($show = mysqli_fetch_array($returnquery)) {
    echo "variable is set to  $show[code]";
    $has_results = true;
}
if (!isset($has_results)) {
    echo "variable is not set";
}
```